# Vimeo on mobile platform questions

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, vimeo

I am using oembed to work with some vimeo videos but I am having a few issues on mobile platforms.

For example, on Android, if I click on the video, the screen goes black and I have to tap again to get the controls to show then you can hit play.

When the video completes, it just sits there and you have to hit the back button.

Additionally once you hit the back button, the thumbnail of the video on the original page is grey and no longer shows the proper vimeo thumbnail.

so, I am having a host of issues and am not really sure where to start. Do I need to work with vimeo's javascript API to make the video behave how I want on mobile?

1. How do I make it autoplay on tap?
2. Can I make it automatically return to the page upon completion?
3. Any insight on the strange greyed out thumbnail?

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: What version of Android are you running and on which device? Older versions offer little control over the video once it starts and goes into fullscreen.

Comment: 4.0.4 is the version on this particular device